# how to profile sequential launched multiple OpenCL kernels by one clFinish?

Tags: profiling, opencl

I have multiple kernels, and they are launched in sequential manner like this:

```
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(..., kernel1, ...);
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(..., kernel2, ...);
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(..., kernel3, ...);
```

and, multiple kernels share one global buffer.

Now, I profile every kernel execution and sum them up to count total execution time by adding the code block after clEnqueueNDRangeKernel:

```
        clFinish(cmdQueue);
        status = clGetEventProfilingInfo(...,&starttime,...);
        clGetEventProfilingInfo(...,&endtime,...);
        time_spent = endtime - starttime;
```

My questions is that how to profile three kernels all together by one clFinish? (like adding one clFinish() after the last kernel launching).

Yes, I give every clEnqueueNDRangeKernel different time event, and get large Negative number.
The detail information:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue,...,&timing_event1);
clFinish(cmdQueue);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event1,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime1,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event1,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime1,NULL);
time_spent1 = endtime1 - starttime1;

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue,...,&timing_event2);
clFinish(cmdQueue);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event2,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime2,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event2,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime2,NULL);
time_spent2 = endtime2 - starttime2;

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue,...,&timing_event3);
clFinish(cmdQueue);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event3,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime3,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event3,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime3,NULL);
time_spent3 = endtime3 - starttime3;

time_spent_all_0 = time_spent1 + time_spent2 + time_spent3;
time_spent_all_1 = endtime3 - starttime1;
```

If I have every clFinish, all profiling values are reasonable, but time_spent_all_1 is about 2 times over time_spent_all_0.
If I remove all clFinish except for the last clFinish, all profiling values are non reasonable.

Thanks to Eric Bainville that I have gotten the result I want: profiling multiple clEnqueueNDRangeKernel by one clFinish. The following is final code I use:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue,...,&timing_event1);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue,...,&timing_event2);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue,...,&timing_event3);
clFinish(cmdQueue);

clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event1,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,sizeof(cl_ulong),&starttime,NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(timing_event3,CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,sizeof(cl_ulong),&endtime,NULL);
time_spent = endtime - starttime;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` will create its own `cl_event`: the last arg of the call is a pointer to a `cl_event`; if this last arg is not 0, a new event will be created.

After a command has completed, the associated event can be queried the start/end profiling info. This event must be released after use (call `clReleaseEvent`).

`clFinish` blocks until all enqueued commands are completed.

You need only one call to `clFinish`, and then you can query profiling info for all events.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that if I just put one clFinish after the last clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, the profiling result become a large Negative number like: -138142371031079. Only when I put clFinish after every clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, the profiling result becomes reasonable.

Comment: Do you have one different event for each enqueued command? Can you update your code to show how events are managed?

Comment: Yes, I always give every clEnqueueNDRangeKernel different time event, and got large Negative number.

Comment: All calls to clGetEventProfilingInfo should be moved *after* the unique clFinish.  The profiling info is valid only after each command has completed.

Comment: Yes! It is true. Thank you so much Eric. Follow your advice, I have gotten what I want. See the original question, the final code is added.

Comment: Nice! You should still get the (end-start) time for each of your kernel calls, and compute the sum. Your GPU may be running some other jobs, and (end3-start1) may be much larger than you expect.  On the other hand, I usually measure the wall clock time (gettimeofday) of several calls to get "user perceived time".

Comment: Yes. I have observed the phenomenon that end3-start1 lager than sum of end-start. But not so much in my computer enviroment. You really have rich experiences on it!