# Difference between two ways of measuring kernel execution times

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I have N separate OpenCL kernels that are run synchronously in a sequential fashion. The second kernel uses results from the first kernel, the third kernel uses those from the second kernel, and etc.

I measured the total "execution" time for the kernels in two different ways:

1) I associate each kernel with an individual event and measure the time for each kernel separately by subtracting the start time from the end time of each event. The total time was computed by adding the times for all the events of all the kernels. In this case, the event wait method was called after executing each kernel.

2) As in 1), I associate each kernel with an event (N kernels and N events). Then, I call the event wait methods at the end after executing all the kernels (namely, all the event wait calls are followed by the series of kernel calls). The total execution time was obtained by subtracting the start time of the first event from the end time of the last event.

The difference between the total times from 1) and 2) was quite significant: ~20% of the total execution time. Where is this 20% lost? Is it associated with (en)queuing the multiple kernels?

How would I go about reducing the "overhead"? Would it reduce the overhead to write a larger kernel by cramming all the kernels into a single large kernel by restructuring the kernels?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you measuring the data copy events, not just the kernel execution events?

Comment: I am measuring both data copy and the kernel execution events. A data copy event is considered another kernel event.

Comment: Almost identical question is asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363780/how-to-profile-sequential-launched-multiple-opencl-kernels-by-one-clfinish. It sounds like 1) in invalid. Does anyone have insights on why 1) is invalid?